# How to do proper memory management using YUI to avoid leaks

Tags: javascript, dom, memory-leaks, yui

We are using YUI's onclick events, but we create and delete dome nodes rapidly and this leads to memory leak.

Consider this example code below, We have many 3 nested divs many times. The top and the bottom div have YUI onclick events attached. What is the proper way to get rid of those dom elements and not leak memory:

I'm really out of any ideas. As you can see I tried implementing our own `destroy` function. Actually `destroy` works and does not leak, but it is slow.

The `destroy2` function is 'copy' of the YUI destroy function where we used to debug what is the problem. It looks like the recursive clean up of YUI can not find the child nodes in the `_instances` dictionary

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.4.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">hi there</div>
        <script>

        YUI().use("node", "event", function(Y) {

            window.Y = Y;

            function destroy(node) {
                (new Y.Node(node)).destroy();
                var children = node.children;
                for (var i = 0; i<children.length; i++) {
                    destroy(children[i]);
                }
            }

            function destroy2(node, recursive) {

                var UID = Y.config.doc.uniqueID ? 'uniqueID' : '_yuid';

                // alert(1);
                if (recursive) {

                    var all = node.all("*");
                    // alert(all);

                    Y.NodeList.each(all, function(n) {
                        instance = Y.Node._instances[n[UID]];
                        // alert(instance);
                        if (instance) {
                           destroy2(instance);
                        }
                    });

                }

                node._node = null;
                node._stateProxy = null;
                delete Y.Node._instances[node._yuid];
                // node.destroy();
            }

            var main = new Y.Node("#main");

            var divs = [];
            var iter = 0;

            Y.later(10, window, function() {

            iter ++ ;
            var i;
            for (i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
                var d = divs[i];
                d.parentNode.removeChild(d);


                // (new Y.Node(d)).destroy(true);
                //destroy(d);
                //destroy2(new Y.Node(d), true);
                (new Y.Node(d)).destroy(true);

            }
            divs = [];

            for (i=0; i<1000; i++) {

                var d = document.createElement("div");

                var i1;
                var i2;
                d.appendChild(i1=document.createElement("div"));
                i1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('inner 1'));
                i1.appendChild(i2=document.createElement("div"));
                i2.appendChild(document.createTextNode('inner 2'));
                Y.on("click", function() {
                    alert("inner click")
                }, i2);

                // try to tell YUI to make Node elements
                Y.Node.one(d);
                Y.Node.one(i1);
                Y.Node.one(i2);

                    // new Y.Node(d);
                // new Y.Node(i1);
                // new Y.Node(i2);

                d.appendChild(document.createTextNode("this is div " + iter + " " + i));

                Y.on("click", function(){ alert("you clicked me");}, d);
                main.appendChild(d);

                //divs.push(i2);
                divs.push(d);

            }

          }, null, true);

        })
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing to avoid  the memory leaks:

```
var destroy = function(dom) {
    var ynode = new Y.Node(dom);
    ynode.purge(true);
    ynode.destroy(true);
}
```

I have to say I'm very disapointed by the YUI documentation that says this for the YUI destroy function.

> With true as a first argument, it works like node.purge(true). The
>   destroy method does more than detaching event subscribers. Read the
>   API docs for details.
>   http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/

I kind of consider this bug in YUI because it does not call recursively purge when you call destroy recursively. Also it looks like the above destroy function is very slow on Firefox 8 (maybe other versions too) I did write my own recursion down the dom tree and called `purge`
and `destroy` without `true`.

Comment: If you believe that behavior is a bug, you should file it at http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/newticket

Comment: According to the ticket, this use case was not reproducible in a more recent version of YUI 3, so apparently this has been resolved.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but a few things stand out in the included code:

1. `var Y = YUI().use(…)` -- `use()` returns the YUI instance. No need to assign `window.Y = Y;`
2. Use `Y.one(el)` instead of `new Y.Node(el)` or `Y.Node.one(el)`
3. Use [event delegation](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/delegation.html) rather than subscribing to the click event on each inner div
4. Use `Y.Node.create('<div><div>inner 1<div>inner2</div></div></div>')`. You probably don't need Node instances for each div
5. You're likely creating more work for yourself over the long term by mixing raw DOM interaction and YUI Nodes.  If you're using YUI, use YUI's APIs.

The most important of those points are #3 and #4. If you use `Node.create` (or `append`, `insert`, `prepend`, etc), the markup passed in won't have Nodes created for each element, only the outer most element.  If you use event delegation, you won't need individual Nodes, which means you can add your div structures and immediately call `node.destroy()` (notice not passing `true` because the inner markup doesn't have nodes needing purging).  `node.destroy()` will purge event listeners, which you don't have because you're using event delegation, and remove the Node from the `_instances` dictionary to free up memory before any user interaction.  If a user clicks on one of the nodes, the event will be caught by the delegate handler and a Node will be created for the `e.target` element.  You're free to call `this.destroy()` inside your event handler to re-purge the `target`'s Node.

YMMV, considering your code snippet doesn't reflect a real use case.  You can also stop into #yui on freenode to get some help or to walk through the issue.

Comment: Using event delegation might be a option but I'm just trying to fix some legacy code. For the same reason we already have a mix of `YUI` nodes and raw `DOM`. We will consider using delegation even though it is easier to just attach events on the particular nodes for us. Thank you for your answer